# Which gets executed faster, a Solidity function or a Web2 backend function?

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3.py

I have a Solidity function which requires an argument which value should be calculated from a value that I retrieve from my Ethereum node via a Web3 call. Once I have the value I have to pass it to a function in my smart contract.

To achieve this I have two scenarios:

**1. Doing the whole logic within the smart contract.**

In this case I take the raw value, pass it to the contract function and do the required processing on chain.

```
// Web3 call at the Web2 backend 

    contract.functions.myFunction(rawValue)

// Solidity part
function myFunction(uint256 rawValue) {

    valueToUse = rawValue * 2;
    // continue the rest of the function
}
```

**2. Doing all needed calculations on my Web2 backend in Python or JS, and use the processed values directly.**

In this case I do all calculations on my server (which don't require built in Solidity functions) and call the function with the processed, ready-to-use values.

```
// Web3 call at the Web2 backend 

    valueToUse = rawValue * 2
    contract.functions.myFunctionB(valueToUse)

// Solidity part
function myFunctionB(uint256 valueToUse ) {
    // continue the rest of the function with the proper value the contract receives from Web3 call
}
```

My question is which solution leads to faster execution time? As doing calculations, loops and other code executions in Solidity cost gas, I think everything that can be done in my backend code should be done there. However I see contracts containing complicated functions (that can be done in backend code too) and the only thing I can think about is they do it because the execution time is less if it's done inside the contract. Am I right? Or what can be the logical reason behind not preparing everything as possible on a web2 server and just use the proper values to call the contract?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically do everything off-chain that you can.  It saves gas, time, and space on the EVM.  I think the only arguments for doing more on-chain:

- usually more user friendly if no nice front end (front ends can be centralization risk)
- there's manipulation risk to off-chain calculation (this is the big one).  As an example, if you're supposed to multiply the rawValue * a users balance for instance.  Of course you could do it off-chain, but you don't really want to trust users with correctly putting in their balance.